# AIR application - unable to open encrypted database using coldfusion.air.SyncManager

Tags: coldfusion, flex4, air

I have an AIR application (written in Flex 4.1.0.16076) that copies data from an unencrypted database to an encrypted database and then tries to open the encrypted database using coldfusion.air.SyncManager's openSession method (Coldfusion-AIR integration library from version 9.0.1). Once the encrypted database is created, the application will be distributed only with the encrypted database.
I use com.adobe.air.crypto.EncryptionKeyGenerator to generate encryption key. I use the same password, first to encrypt the database and then try to open it.
The database is successfully generated but when I try to open it, I get the following error:
SQLError: 'Error #3125: Unable to open the database file.', details:'An encryption key cannot be specified when the database is not encrypted.', operation:'open', detailID:'1011'

I'm passing the encryption key to openSession method.

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Dilip

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, with AIR, a DB must be created as an encrypted DB. An unencrypted DB cannot be later encrypted. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: You are right... you cannot convert an unencrypted db to an encrypted db. And so, I'm table-by-table 'exporting' data from unencrypted db to the newly created encrypted db.

Comment: but I'm unable to open the encrypted database with openSession method!